# Maximum of the function $F(x,y,z):=\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-z)}{1-(1-xy)z}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am stuck with finding the maximum of the function
\begin{align}
F(x,y,z):=\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-z)}{1-(1-xy)z}
\end{align}
on the compact interval $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1].$

I think the Lagrange multiplier may work, but I have no idea to set a constraint function. Is there any hint I can follow or another method ? Any suggestions I will be grateful.

Comment: Afraid you can take the partial derivatives and equate to zero. [Some search](https://tio.run/##JY3BDgIhDETvfAXHlqArGhP/xXjYZFExAg1hE@DnkUoPnebNZEo1v2O43Cj17jzFlGVawxa9oORCBuHXAlAUmENBVVkrqsbacBmbDcUIddFVN5TPmOT/lC5IyDt9LczO4xSYmQ/795M2@vyYxDEZmZcF/m3sFccI7P0H) finds the maximum value $\approx 0.0294$ near $(0.41,0.41,0.7)$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin you used random function, the answers could have been wrong....(because random is not always random :)

Comment: Sure, but I repeated the process some times, it gives nearly the same values.

Comment: This function appears in the Beuker's proof of irrationality of $\zeta (3)$. A proof does not really need the maximum of this function, but just an upper bound. See [this blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/10/irrationality-of-zeta-2-and-zeta-3-part-2.html?m=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the logarithm, then just differentiate it.
EDIT
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln F=\frac1x+\frac1{x-1}-\frac{yz}{1-z+xyz}=0 \\
\frac1y+\frac1{y-1}-\frac{xz}{1-z+xyz}=0 \\
\frac1z+\frac1{z-1}-\frac{xy-1}{1-z+xyz}=0$$
Multiply the first by $x$, the second by $y$ to get $x/(x-1)=y/(y-1)$.  Then turn the first equation into a linear equation in $z$.

Comment: This method is very useful. After doing some simple algebra, we can the get the maximum of the given function on the compact set $[0,1]^3$ at $x=y=\sqrt{2}-1$ and $z=1/\sqrt{2}$ Thanks, I learned a lesson.

Answer (score 5):

Taking partial derivatives with respect to $x,y,z$ we have
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = -\dfrac{(y - 1) y (z - 1) z (x^2 y z - 2 x (z - 1) + z - 1)}{(z (x y - 1) + 1)^2}\\
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} =-\dfrac{(x - 1) x (z - 1) z (x y^2 z - 2 y z + 2 y + z - 1)}{(x y z - z + 1)^2}\\
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} =-\dfrac{(x - 1) x (y - 1) y (x y z^2 - z^2 + 2 z - 1)}{(x y z - z + 1)^2}
\end{cases}$$
Equating them to $0$ and dropping unnecessary factors which clearly don't lead to a maximum, we get
$$\begin{cases}
x^2 y z - 2 x (z - 1) + z - 1=0\\
x y^2 z - 2 y z + 2 y + z - 1=0\\
x y z^2 - z^2 + 2 z - 1 =0
\end{cases}$$
Then the desired solution is, according to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+y+z+-+2+x+%28z+-+1%29+%2B+z+-+1%3D0%2C+x+y%5E2+z+-+2+y+z+%2B+2+y+%2B+z+-+1%3D0%2C+x+y+z%5E2+-+z%5E2+%2B+2+z+-+1+%3D0)
$$\begin{cases}
x = \sqrt{2} - 1\\ 
y = \sqrt{2} - 1\\
z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $F(x,y,z)\ge0$ is continuous on a compact maximum and minimum exist. On the boundary it easy to check that $F=0$ therefore we can search the maximum by $\nabla F=0$ which leads to the condition

$$z=\frac1{1-\sqrt{xy}}=\frac{1-2x}{x^2y-2x+1} =\frac{1-2y}{y^2x-2y+1}$$